# Framer Motion Variant issue

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, framer-motion

I'm upgrading framer-motion progressively from v1.11.1 to 6.0.0 but I have this issue:

I've created an animationsUtils where I have these two animations:

```
const defaultTransition = {
  stiffness: 100,
  dumping: 30,
  duration: 0.6,
  when: "beforeChildren",
  staggerChildren: 0.2,
};

export const FADE_LEFT = {
  initial: { opacity: 0, x: -60 },
  variants: {
    start: {
      opacity: 1,
      x: 0,
      transition: defaultTransition,
    },
  },
};

export const HOVER_SHADOW = {
  whileHover: "hoverShadow",
  variants: {
    hoverShadow: {
      y: -8,
      boxShadow: 'rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.09) 0px 2px 2px,
    rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.09) 0px 4px 4px, rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.09) 0px 8px 8px,
    rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.09) 0px 16px 16px, rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.09) 0px 32px 32px,
    rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.09) 0px 64px 64px',
      transition: defaultTransition,
    },
  },
};
```

I've created my component making a merge between them using Deepmerge:

```
<motion.div
{...combine(FADE_RIGHT, HOVER_SHADOW)}
className="blog-posts__text"
        >
          <p className="blog-posts__category">
              <a href="#">text</a>
          </p>
</motion.div>
```

And added my inView property on a parent component.

And it doesn't work.

I don't know what's wrong, if the deepmerge (that somehow works on other stuff but not in this component), or my parent inView function (that works perfectly on every component but this), or maybe my animations have changed from version to version.

My combine function:

```
export const combine = (...args) => {
  return deepmerge.all([...args]);
};
```

P.S.:
I've tested join them up into a single function but it doesn't work either.
But: if I test these functions separately, it works!